# How to wrap make all macro in Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I had a problem with my working make file.

I have large "make all" definition that makes a lot of stuff, but today I need add a "make tests" definition that will be runed to create test binary that will be runed to test device.
So the "make tests" will only define a variable TEST=1, and then run "make all" command.

So I tried as follow:

```
tests : 
    $(C_FLAGS_F) = $(C_FLAGS_F) -D TESTS=1        #C_FLAGS_F hold whole make flags so I add additional flag -D to declare TESTS
    all
```

but in these combination gcc give me an error:

```
make: [tests] Error 127 (ignored)
all
make: all: Command not found
```

So my question is how to achieve this in makefile

Comment: For starters, you probably should do `C_FLAGS_F =...` instead of `$(C_FLAGS_F) =...`

Comment: C_FLAGS_F are declared previously, so I want to add to existinf C_FLAGS_F additional option "-D"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
tests: C_FLAGS_F += -D TESTS=1

tests: all
```